# Using Android API with other application in Android Platform

Tags: android, synchronization

I want to find out if it is possible to create Android API's that can be used or implemented in other applications, so that they can be synchronized. For example, there is a calendar application and a separate application that has the details of all the meetings of the day. Can the calendar & the other app be synchronized to get a new application in which the calendar itself shows the meetings for the day?

Where can I learn more about these API's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not very clear, but what I understood from your question that you want to create two applications which uses same datasource.

To Achieve this, you can use ContentProvider, By ContentProviders an application make exposure of its data to other applications. To create and Use content providers look into following links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Comment: I want to know whether there are applications which can be used with other applications?? Do these applications provide the customization to be used with new applications that are being developed?

Comment: In ios i have seen these kinds of application synchronization(or sharing the data) so is it not available in Android??

Comment: as I told, for syncronization purpose of data ContentProviders are provided.